# Can I limit IIS to use one rather than two processors in iis

Tags: iis

Our ASP.NET app uses a component that is licensed by the number of processor cores. Unfortunately, our customer wants to deploy the app onto a multi-function server (IIS, SQL Server, file server, etc.) that exceeds the number of processor cores for which the customer is licensed: they are allowed four cores but have two processors with four cores each.  I configure IIS to use only one processor?

so i tried to set application pools settings

in applicationpool ->advance setting -> process affinity enable =ture
and i have set number of working process =1

after i have checked in tast manager w3wp.exe-> set affinity its all core are selected

where i made error...
thank u